# integer manipulation by reading its index

Tags: java

I have a integer value like 4590897, what i have to do is i have to shuffle this integer in a way so that i get output 4759980, its like rading first number and last number and creating a new number. integer value can be any.

i tried some code like by converting number in char array and then iterating it and appending it in StringBuilder but not getting desired result.
Code below

```
public final class class2 {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 15670;
    StringBuilder s2 = new StringBuilder();
    String s1 = String.valueOf(a);
    char[] ch = s1.toCharArray();
    //System.out.println(ch.length);
    Outerloop:
    for(int i = 0; i <=ch.length-1;i++){
        //System.out.println(ch[i]);
        for(int j = ch.length-1; j >=0; j--){
            s2.append(ch[i]);
            s2.append(ch[j]);
            break;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(s2);
}
```

}

i have to shuffle this integer in a way so that i get output 4759980

Comment: Do you specifically aim at 4759980 or any random order of digits that were initially present?

Comment: random number, number can range from [1-10000000]

Comment: you can split the array into two parts. take one by one charac from end of second part  and place it an alternative positions in first part.

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is now not clear what you want. At first I thought you wanted a random order, but that may not be the case. Do you mean you want to alternate between the first and last character and then work your way inwards?

Comment: yes exactly that's exactly what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this! I am first converting the number to a string. Then I add the first and last digit, the second and the before last digit, etc. Then, I make sure that the string is the same length as the starting one (in case of numbers with odd-number of digits).

```
public int scramble(int number) {
    String numberString = Integer.toString(number);
    int numberLength = numberString.length();
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < (numberLength + 2) / 2; i++) {
        result += numberString.charAt(i);
        result += numberString.charAt(numberLength - i - 1);
    }
    //Making sure that the resulting string is the same length as the original
    //Initially, the result for a number with an odd number of digits, such as 12345
    //will be 152344. So you need to make sure the last digit is removed.
    result = result.substring(0, numberLength);
    return Integer.parseInt(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this. First you decompose your number into digits and then you randomly add them back to each other, by picking a random position to add the digit...

```
public int scramble(int number) {

    //Convert the integer to an Array of strings where each string represents a digit
    String[] digits = Integer.toString(number).split("");

    //Add the individual digits to a list in random order, using a random position
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String digit: digits) {
        int position = (int) (Math.random()*(resultList.size()));
        resultList.add(position, digit);
    }

    //Convert the list with digits in random order to a string
    String resultString ="";
    for (String digit: resultList) {
        resultString += digit;
    }

    //Convert the resulting string to an integer and return
    return Integer.parseInt(resultString);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, i tried you running your code. it's running fine but not giving desired output like it passed value 130. Expected output: 103. output got 301

Comment: You shouldn't expect anything, as the result is going to be random. So either 13, 31, 103, 130, 301 or 310.

Comment: Please update your question. It was not clear what you were after (otherwise I would not have given this answer).

Comment: but condition is i have to shuffle the number in that way that it reads value from both end and generate shuffled number.

Answer (score 0):

Take two pointers, start and end. Iterate through the string and append the character from start and end to a new string. Increment start and decrement end untill start and end is same.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
      int num = 45908971;
      System.out.println(alternate(num));      
   }


   private static int alternate(int num){
      String numStr = Integer.toString(num);
      int start = 0;
      int end = numStr.length()-1;
      StringBuffer newNum = new StringBuffer();
      while(start<=end) {
         newNum.append(numStr.charAt(start++)).append(numStr.charAt(end--));
      }
      return Integer.parseInt(new String(newNum.toString()));
   }
```